# Fail2Ban not sending IP to iptables

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

Fail2Ban seems to be working fine

```
Status for the jail: nginx-php
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed: 22
|  `- File list:    /var/log/nginx/access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 1
   `- Banned IP list:   46.32.125.42
```

But on iptables it doesnt show the ip being blocked

Iptables:

```
root@box-01:~# iptables -L INPUT -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1501 packets, 415K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  328 40327 f2b-nginx-php  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
```

Comment: 2021-11-29 12:24:59,408 fail2ban.filter         [850]: INFO    [nginx-php] Found 46.32.125.42 - 2021-11-29 12:24:59
2021-11-29 12:24:59,881 fail2ban.actions        [850]: NOTICE  [nginx-php] Ban 46.32.125.42

Comment: Generally fail2ban has several possible approaches for blocking hosts and your check may not appropriate. For example when your config used `ipset` blocked IP adresses will never show up In iptables output … Also `iptables-save` may give more output

Comment: try `iptables -S f2b-nginx-php`